# adding a parser to a java applet that works as a web browser

Tags: java, parsing, browser, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I am trying to make a web browser that works entirely on voice commands (i.e speech-to-text and vice versa using sphinx.)

I have a Java applet, but I don't know how to add a parser to it so that different parts of different websites go to a particular segment in my browser.

What are the necessary steps to add a parser to a web browser applet?

Comment: That's a pretty ambitious wish. I'd suggest searching the internet for java speech parsers and first trying to see if you can make a "just a speech parser" program work before hooking it into an attempt at a fully speech-operated browser.

Comment: i have googled alot, was not able to find any suitable outcome

Comment: then you have been googling for the wrong thing. Search for "java text to speech" and "java speech synthesis" and you'll get an amazing number of hits.

Comment: actually,i m working on a project and my job is to give a web browser on which a certain no. of news websites can be surfed.speech to text is not my part of job.so i want to know how i can parse those similar structured websites on my browser applet?

Comment: alternative suggestion: don't use java applets. They're incredibly insecure and not meant to be browsers. Just pick the browser you like, and write two addons for it. One for the website-to-speech part, and one for the speech-to-browser-commands part. Now you have something the rest of the world will want to use too, without being both slow and easily zero-day exploitable.

Comment: thanx for the suggestion. i will think over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i am able to make a fully speech based web browser. I used **Jsoup** for extracting various elements of any web page. Then with the help of **sphinx** and **freetts** i allowed users to interact with browser by using speech commands only.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need java applet, it creates too many issues. You need something like pocketsphinx.js:

https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js

This technology can give you access to content of the browser with javascript, a way easier way to manage things.